# Не работает RewriteRule ЧПУ

Tags: чпу

Уже несколько дней не могу решить проблему...Замучился вконец.
В общем есть локальный сайт на openserver 5.2.2(apache 2.4) по адресу domains/myshop.local.Создается на движке smarty.В папке www находится index.php и htaccess.
Есть вот такая ссылка [http://myshop.local/www/product/12,которая](http://myshop.local/www/product/12,%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F) должна "пониматся" как ?controller=$1&id=$2
вот код код htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8  
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

php_flag register_globals on

 RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ /?controller=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
 RewriteRule ^(product)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ /?controller=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css│js│jpg│gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Соотвественно,переходя по этой ссылке выбивает ошибку 404.Причем,когда ссылку пишешь через get параметр,а не ЧПУ - ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ.
С регулярками,только что с бубном не танцевал).Как решить эту проблему ума не приложу.
На всякий случай приложу код php:

```
<!-- шаблон главной страницы -->

  {foreach $rsProducts as $item name = products}
  <div class="product">
  <a href="/product/{$item['name']}/">
  <img src="/images/products/{$item['image']}" alt="" width="100" height="100">
  </a></br>
  <a href="product/{$item['id']}">{$item['name']}</a>
  </div>
  {if $smarty.foreach.products.iteration mod 3 === 0}
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
```

Заранее,спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Помогли на хабре.Решение:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?controller=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]
```